# Is it possible to hide the original object of an array from the camera?

Tags: modifiers

I'm working on a project where a second person need to add images to the postrendered image. The main object is a fruit crate in which I used an array to make the frontal wood bars:
[image]

My idea to solve this problem is to make 2 different renderings from the same camera, one where I don't see the anterior set of bars possible by uncheck the camera view in the array modifier, and one in which I don't see all the other elements, ecxept for the object created from the array. So in this way the other person could stack the images and obtain a realistic result without further work. For example if I want to add an apple, I start with the background, then I add my fuit over it and finally I add the wood bars. Is my idea practicable? Is there another way of doing it?

Comment: Why use an array at all? Why not make all bars separate instances of the same object? That way you can even put them in different render layers and render all in one go.

Comment: You can use either different render layers, cryptomatte layers, object ID layers. You'll need to export in a file format that supports different passes like exr

Comment: @Gorgious I didn't know render layers, I have found how tu use them as you have suggested. How can I find the proper usage of the others layers that you mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the faster approach is to use Render Layer. A render layer is a way to separate objects in the scene and render them separately, I'll show quickly how to use them for the use I needed:

1. Create folders to keep the background objects and what should be put over

[image]

2. Create a new Render Layer (Use the new option in the menu that will show once you click)
   [image]
3. Remove the check from the elements that will be part of the background
   [image]
4. Switch to the new layer and remove the check from all the other objects

   [image]

   [image]

Now Blender will render 2 images, one for each layer, and with a photo editor you can simply paste the background, insert the fruit you want in the crate and then paste over all the final layer.